# Swift: CoreData FetchRequest within Class doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to fetch from my Core Data Entity within a Notification Delegate Class, but it can't access it.

It's the same @Environment and @FetchRequest as within another view, which works great, but it seems like it can't access the entity from this class.

I'm sorry if this is basic or solution is somewhere else, but I just can't find an answer that works.
Thanks!

```
class NotificationDelegate: NSObject, ObservableObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context: NSManagedObjectContext

@Published var countdownToSee: EventEntity?

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.badge, .banner, .sound])
}


@FetchRequest(
    entity: EventEntity.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: []) var upcomingEvents: FetchedResults<EventEntity>

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    
    if response.actionIdentifier == "OPEN" {
        print("Open")
        print(upcomingEvents.count)
        
    }
    
    completionHandler()
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `@Environment` and `@FetchRequest` outside of a `View` "properly" `@Environment` get initialized but usually doesn't update.

To fetch from CoreData you'll have to use the ["old way"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH6-SW1). Attached you'll see the link with more information. It is old but a lot of it still applies.

```
let moc = …
let employeesFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Employee")

do {
    let fetchedEmployees = try moc.executeFetchRequest(employeesFetch) as! [EmployeeMO]
} catch {
    fatalError("Failed to fetch employees: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: With some modification; this worked absolutely fantastic. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Wood Would you be able to share what those modifications were in relation to your original question? Also stuck with this and not 100% clear what the solution is. thanks!

Comment: @Simon the changes were to make the `NSFetchRequest` specific to his code. The first would be to get the managed object context or `moc` from wherever the stack is. If you are using the standard setup that comes from a new project it would be something like `PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext` or pass it as an argument, etc. The second would be the initialization for the `NSFetchRequest` You can use something like `EventEntity.fetchRequest()`or  `NSFetchRequest(entityName: "EventEntity")`.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are no views ind SwiftUI, I guess you cannot do that. Consider rather fetching the information you need in one view and passing them to a class afterwards.

```
struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: EntityClassName.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \EntityClassName.name, ascending: false)],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "someAttributeName == %@", NSNumber(value: false)),
        animation: .default)
    private var myEntities: FetchedResults<EntityClassName>
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Do Whatever you want with the CoreData data...")
            onAppear {
                // Create your class that needs the information and put it where you need it
                var myClass = MyClass(needsData: myEntities)
                // Do something with it, or not if it does all it needs to do on itself.
            }
    }
}
```

You could for example also save the data in a singleton when you use them in the onAppear function and then in your NotificationDelegate take the information from the singleton. Not a beatiful solution, but it should work.

Answer (score -1):

@Environment is used by Views in the SwuftUI view hierarchy. Your class `NotificationDelegate` is not a View in the view hierarchy.

When you create the instance of your view, you will need to pass it the managed object context in the initializer.

I assume you are currently trying to pass it with the `.environmentObject()`, so instead pass it in the initializer.